# Save File As Macro causes error if existing file is already open

Tags: vba, excel

I have created vba code for saving excel workbooks in a folder. But i am getting run time error 1004, when already existed file is opened and other same excel workbook is also created.

```
Private Sub CommandButton14_Click()

    Dim folderpath As String

    Dim Fname As String

    Dim file As String


    Fname = MyForm.SCC.Value

    folderpath = ActiveWorkbook.Path

    Workbooks.Open Filename:= _

        ("" & folderpath & "\" & Fname & "- Q3 2016" & ".xlsx")

        ' for adding explaination sheet from PAM sheet into destination sheet

    ' Section E: please update the name of excel workbook if the name of this excel workbook changed

    Windows("OEM PAM Sizer 2016 - v1.xlsm").Activate

    Sheets("Automation Content definition").Visible = True

    Sheets("Automation Content definition").Select

    Sheets("Automation Content definition").Copy After:=Workbooks( _

        "" & Fname & "- Q3 2016" & ".xlsx").Sheets(1)

    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").Activate

    Range("a1").Select

    file = "" & folderpath & "\" & Fname & "- Q3 2016" & ".xlsx"

    FileExist (file)


    Windows("OEM PAM Sizer 2016 - v1.xlsm").Close savechanges:=False

End sub
```

Answer (score 2):

If the file is opened - close it.
Microsoft gives some tricks how to understand whether the file is opened:

```
Function IsFileOpen(filename As String)
    Dim filenum As Integer, errnum As Integer

    On Error Resume Next   ' Turn error checking off.
    filenum = FreeFile()   ' Get a free file number.
    ' Attempt to open the file and lock it.
    Open filename For Input Lock Read As #filenum
    Close filenum          ' Close the file.
    errnum = Err           ' Save the error number that occurred.
    On Error GoTo 0        ' Turn error checking back on.

    ' Check to see which error occurred.
    Select Case errnum

        ' No error occurred.
        ' File is NOT already open by another user.
        Case 0
         IsFileOpen = False

        ' Error number for "Permission Denied."
        ' File is already opened by another user.
        Case 70
            IsFileOpen = True

        ' Another error occurred.
        Case Else
            Error errnum
    End Select

End Function
```

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/291295/macro-code-to-check-whether-a-file-is-already-open

Another option is to name your file differently.